# How can i create variables with for loop?

Tags: python

i started to learn python and i want to create variables with loop. I wrote the code below but I couldn't reach what I wanted.

```
for i in range(50):
    var["i%d"% i]=IntVar()
```

i want something like that:

```
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
     .
     .
```

How can i do that, thanks for help.

Comment: looks like you need this: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists

Comment: "i started to learn python and i want to create variables with loop ... " The next step in your learning is to suppress that desire. Use a proper data structure such as a list or dictionary instead.

Comment: you don't need to declare variables in python.
but if you are interested in typing
```
from typing import List

int_list = List[int]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually create a variable with a different name this way. You can add values to a list though, and gather the values later on, put hem inside variables... Why do you need to create so many variables ? Maybe you can skip that step and use a list. Try working this way around your problem.

Comment: Im using variables for tickboxes etc. in tkinter.